# How can I remove the parentheses from the last item in NSArray

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray

I am creating an Array from a .txt file that looks like this:

```
 Bears;wins;24;losses;15
 Lions;wins;34;losses;10
```

etc.

When I get an array for each line with:

```
 NSArray *myArray = [content componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"];
```

I get an array like this:

```
 ("Bears;wins;24;losses;15
 ",
 "Lions;wins;34;losses;10
 ")
```

When I parse out the semicolon i get this:

```
 (Bears,
 wins,
 24,
losses,
 "15
 "
 ),
 (
 Lions,
 wins,
 34,
 losses,
 "10
 ")
```

The problem is that when I want to move the objects say make it look/print like this:

```
 Lions,34,10,wins,losses
```

The output is instead coming out like this:

```
 Lions,34
 ,10,wins,losses
```

How can I fix this to keep it all on one line?

Comment: Show your code. Keep in mind that the parentheses and quotes are simply comping from the `description` method of `NSArray` when you log the array.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was when I was separating the line with:

```
 NSArray *arr = [content componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"];
```

I fixed it by separating the line with:

```
 NSArray *arr = [content componentsSeparatedByString:@"\r\n"];
```